# Gecko FX 45 accessing frames.

Tags: c#, events, geckofx

I am wondering how I can execute some JS in each frame in GeckoFX 45.

So suppose I have this nested frame structure on page.

```
Topframe //TOP:0
  frame[0] //TOP:0/Frame:0
    frame[0] //TOP:0/Frame:0/Frame:0
    frame[1] //TOP:0/Frame:0/Frame:1
       frame[0] //TOP:0/Frame:0/Frame:1/Frame:0
       frame[1] //TOP:0/Frame:0/Frame:1/Frame:1
  frame[1] //TOP:0/Frame:1
```

Let say have JS and I need to insert this JS to each document in each frame on page. I also need some information about relationship (parent, child, sibling) between individual frames (something like commented section of code).

I was looking in to events provided by Gecko interface and only event FrameNavigating seem to be related to frames, but this does not seem to working properly, for example I always get exception when I am just asking for bool property main frame.

Any hints ?

Comment: I am fairly sure DocumentCompleted event gets called when FrameNavigating is finished...

Comment: Well dunno, but eventually was able to obtain document from top frame and iterate through it to obtain iframe and frame elements and then iterate through them again